# css animated icon resize

Tags: css, scss-lint

how you use $ in css

```
[http://codepen.io/jlong/pen/KBhDf][1]
```

in the above mentioned link on the 3rd line $heartbeat-size: 10px; I wanted to know how to use this element in the style sheet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll have to be more specific with your question. I'm not sure what you mean and generally you'll have to explain what you have tried before someone will be able to help.

Comment: yes I want to use `$heartbeat-size: 10px;` in the external style sheet but I don't know how and under what class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, here is the processed `CSS` result of the `scss` in your pen:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  14% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  28% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  42% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  14% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  28% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  42% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  14% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  28% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  42% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  14% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  28% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  42% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

/* Styles for old versions of IE */
.heartbeat {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

/* :not(:required) hides this rule from IE9 and below */
.heartbeat:not(:required) {
  -webkit-animation: heartbeat 1300ms ease 0s infinite normal;
  -khtml-animation: heartbeat 1300ms ease 0s infinite normal;
  -moz-animation: heartbeat 1300ms ease 0s infinite normal;
  -ms-animation: heartbeat 1300ms ease 0s infinite normal;
  -o-animation: heartbeat 1300ms ease 0s infinite normal;
  animation: heartbeat 1300ms ease 0s infinite normal;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.heartbeat:not(:required):after, .heartbeat:not(:required):before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: #e87;
}
.heartbeat:not(:required):before {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 12px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 12px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  width: 36px;
  height: 24px;
}
.heartbeat:not(:required):after {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 12px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 12px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  top: 0;
  left: 12px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<span class="heartbeat">Loading...</span>
```

---

To understand the principle...

Using variables in `CSS` is not possible at the moment and is unlikely to be possible anytime soon.

This is only available using CSS pre-processors, such as [`less`](http://lesscss.org/) or [`sass`](http://sass-lang.com/).

[`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/) and [`codepen`](http://codepen.io) allow you to use `scss` (sass) in the `CSS` panel and correctly output the processed `CSS` when rendering.

[`sass.js`](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/) is a library that allows you to use `.sass` files in `<link>` tags and processes them into valid `CSS` at load time.

---

It is likely that major browsers will soon be capable of processing `.scss`, `.sass` or `.less` files natively and it is already possible by using browser extensions.

This, however, does not mean `CSS` will ever support variables.

Comment: thanks for the support but how can I change the size of it in the same css file.

Comment: Change it to any value in `px` that is a multiple of 6. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgQVLZ . Than select View compiled CSS. And copy/paste.

Comment: This worked just fine for me. I am using the `<i class="fas fa-comment"></i>` icon from Fontawsome, and when I add the `scale` property to the icon, it looks pixeled. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Paula, it's fixable, but not without a [mcve]. Consider asking a separate question, ideally providing a runnable snippet. Also note this answer is outdated. Today you can use variables in CSS directly.