# Why is a textnode rendered below its parents` ::before by default?

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

On writing-up an answer for a different question on SO, I made this snippet:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light');

/* relevant CSS */
div {
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left:0;
}
div>span {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

/* rest is just styling - should be irrelevant for the question */


div {
  font: normal normal normal 2rem/1 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-width: 15rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  background-color: #bada55;
  border-radius: .4rem;
}
div[orange]:before {
  background-color: #f50;
}
div:hover::before {
  opacity:.65;
}

body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
center-me-please {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: transparent url(http://lorempixel.com/g/1200/800/fashion) no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
}
```

```html
<center-me-please>
  
  <div><span>#bada55</span></div>
  <div orange>not so #bada55</div>
```

I was surprised to notice the `::before` element is rendered above textnodes (orange element) and, in order to prevent it from happening. I had to wrap the textnode in a `span` element and give it a non-negative `z-index` and a non-static `position` (#bada55 element).

On inspection, while the `::before` element has a default (expected) value of `z-index` (`auto`), the textnode doesn't seem to have one at all (or at least Chrome's not able to show it).

Up to now I liked to think of myself as a `z-index` little ninja, idea partly backed-up by developing [`this toy`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/tsuevt5a/) to help friends and colleagues better understand  stacking contexts principle and `z-index` in general.

As you might have guessed, I'm looking for any explanation on why `::before` is not rendered below everything else in an element by default (it's first, therefore below, right?) and for any evidence about this being either a (known?) bug or intended (by design?) behavior.

A spec I might have missed or misinterpreted would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::before` *is* painted below text content by default — and the default case is when [everything is non-positioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue/11088328#11088328).

But your `::before` is absolutely positioned. Positioned boxes are always painted in front of non-positioned boxes. Refer to [section 9.9.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#layers) (emphases mine):

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. **the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.**
> 6. **the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.**
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

Wrapping your text content in a positioned `span` causes it to be painted in front of the `::before` content as expected since then you have two positioned boxes in source order.

Comment: You could have waited for the bounty. You know I'd have set one, right? :)

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: You can always set one after the fact ;)

Comment: I know, I'm going to. Not because I'm expecting better answers. But because I'd love to see more answers like yours, in general.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: Aw thanks. I gather you've been cracking your head at this for a while?

Comment: 2 hours. After first, I decided to ask it and it took me ~1 hour to write and clean up initial snippet.